# Calculate areas with one raster layer and one shapefile (polygons)

Tags: merge, polygon, raster, area, calculation

I am having some problems figuring out how to solve a problem in R. I have one shapefile that contains around 300 polygons (areas) and one raster layer (LULC map) that contains different values (such as infrastructure, forest, lakes and so one) for different pixels. My task is to get the area of each polygon in the raster file (LULC map) and then subtract a value (in my case three of the values indicates on infrastructure) from the total area of each polygon.

I am new at programming in R and using this kind of process, and would therefore really appreciate any help! I just need some help to understand how to solve this and in what steps to divide this into. So bear with me :)

I have managed to read in my shapefile and rasterize:

```
# Read shapefile into R
jvk_18 <- readOGR(dsn = "JKV_18_19/Alla_kretsar_geografisk1.shp")

#Change CRS on shapefile to same as rasterlayer, copy the one from raster layer
jvk_18 <- spTransform(jvk_18, 
                      CRS("+proj=utm +zone=33 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs"))

# Set up a raster template for a 1000 degree grid in resulution.
ext <- extent(268607.50, 920075.4, 6133580, 7670992)
gridsize <- 100
r <- raster(ext, res = gridsize)

# Rasterize shapefile
rr <- rasterize(jvk_18, r)

#Plot raster (axes = T to get the map I want)
plot(rr, axes = T)
```

Then I have read in my raster file:

```
> mark_raster <- raster("Marktäckedata/nmd2018bas_generaliserad_v1_0.tif")
> plot(mark_data)
```

So this how far I have come! So my question to all of you is how to proceed?
- Both have the same CRS (WGS84)

- Both have the same extent
- I am guessing that my rasterized shapefile needs to be at the same resolution as my raster file (that is 10*10)? Should I do this?
- Is there more I need to do before start merging or calculating?
- Should I merge the two layers before any calculation and in that case, do I need to do anything before merging?
- Is there any other way to calculate the areas?

I understand that this a lot to ask for! And any help would be really appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

You could continue down this road, but I think it would be easier to simply run zonal statistics using the spatialEco package.

```
zonal.stats(x, y, stats = c("min", "mean", "max"))
#x = Polygon object of class SpatialPolygonsDataFrame
#y = rasterLayer object of class raster
```

https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/spatialEco/versions/1.3-0/topics/zonal.stats